# How can I show the Unique Constraints in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, unique, constraints

show uniques???

Comment: If you don't take the time to write a proper question, Why should anyone bother to write a proper answer? Waht did you try, what were the results? SO is *not* a natural language interface for google.

Comment: Google does not show the answer: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mysql+show+unique+constraints

Comment: Unique is a key/index, search google for unique index gives you the page i got the syntax from as the second result, the rest was just some constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
show indexes from package WHERE non_unique = 0 and Key_name != 'PRIMARY';
```